# My Android studio stops working and is showing this error

Tags: android-studio

My Android Studio stops working and it's showing this error:

[Internal Error: Invalid path exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p93ym.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted and reinstalled the IDE and it works fine.

Google should really check their releases before going out official. If I were to work on such an important project, this would waste many hours of my time, as well as the time of users, and even the time of those who called on to support them (here on Stackoverflow), for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your `build-cache` from the `.android` directory.